# delphi compare text file contents

Tags: delphi, file, compare

We need to compare the contents of two (or more) text files to determine if we need to create a backup. If they differ we create a new backup.

I currently use the CRC value of each file to check for differences but I was wondering if there is a more efficient or elegant way of detecting differences between to files.

```
//Use madZIP to calculate the CRC fior this file
GetUncompressedFileInfo(Filename_1, Size_1, NewCRC);

//Use madZIP to calculate the CRC fior this file
GetUncompressedFileInfo(Filename_2, Size_2, OldCRC);

//if ThisFileHash = ExistingFileHash then
if (OldCRC <> NewCRC) then
  CreateABackup;
```

Regards, Pieter.

Comment: Only thing Id do is check sizes first, if the size is different then so is the file. Its a simple but quick precheck you can possibly speed it up with if the size is different not to bother doing the CRC check.

Comment: What exactly do you think is not efficient and elegant for the CRC solution?

Comment: I am rewriting out existing solution and I'm looking for ways to improve the existing code. I'm not saying that CRC is inefficient, but there may be another way of getting the same result that suit my needs better.

Comment: If you're rewriting, consider using RSYNC instead of doing your own flaky incremental backup. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRC is probably more accurate, and pretty efficient. However do you need to check the contents?

I'm assuming you're checking the CRC to see if a modification has been made and re-backup the updated file. In which case FileAge() would do just fine.

Comment: Yes. We only want to make a backup if the contents has changed.

Comment: Like BugFinder says then. FileSize before CRC should save you some work most of the time. Otherwise CRC is the most efficent method I know of to actually compare contents.

Comment: Any suggestions for fast and efficient CRC routines?

Comment: In addition to CRC, it should be better to check the file size. The more parameters you compare, the better. But for checking `FileAge()` be aware that, with NTFS, you may discover a one-hour change depending on the Daylight saving time zone...

Answer (score 7):

CRC is not a safe method to detect file changes - cryptographic hashes (like MD5 or SHA1) are much better.

Another approach (like the one used by build systems) is to compare file dates. If the file is newer than backup, a new backup is needed.

Comment: There is no need for a cryptographic secure hash for this purpose. It's just a backup scenario.

Comment: @ba__friend: CRC has a higher chance of false positive, it can say two files are the same even if they are not. The safest way is to compare both date and time of the last change and a hash with enough number of bits to ensure small chance of collision. 128, 256 or event 512 bit hash. In fact almost all good backup and other similar SW works this way.

Comment: +1 for CRC false positives, which may be a problem for a backup scenario. But file date could laid into false negative, since I discovered that sometimes, with NTFS, `FileAge` may return a one-hour change depending on the Daylight saving time zone...

Comment: That is why you always check for hash if file date is different.

Comment: `FileAge()` uses the local clock and timezone (by calling `FileTimeToLocalFileTime()`). If you use UTC comparisons instead, you won't run into timezone issues. `FileTimeToLocalFileTime()` expects a UTC timestamp as input, which means `FileAge()` retreives UTC to begin with and then translates it internally. Depending on Delphi version, `FileAge()` uses either `FindFirstFile()` or `GetFileAttributesEx()` to access the UTC timestamp. You can do the same manually in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider using an incremental backup.

I've published some optimized file versioning functions for our [SynProject](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=SynProject%20Features) Open Source tool. The `TVersions` class, in [ProjectVersioning](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynProject/ProjectVersioning.pas) unit allows binary diff storage inside a zip container.

Our proprietary but faster-than-zip [SynLZ algorithm](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=32) is used to store incremental differences. It works very well on practice.

See e.g. `TVersions.FillStrings` method for retrieving a list of files to be updated.

Be aware that you may discover a one-hour difference, depending on the current Daylight saving time. Here is how we allow a per-date comparison:

```
function SameFileDateWindows(FileDate1,FileDate2: integer): boolean;
// we allow an exact one Hour round (NTFS bug on summer time zone change)
begin
  dec(FileDate1,FileDate2);
  result := (FileDate1=0) or (FileDate1=1 shl 11) or (FileDate1=-(1 shl 11));
end;
```

We don't read the file content here. For a backup purpose, it's enough to rely on the file date to mark the file as to be compared. Then a differential diff is performed about both versions of the file. If the file content is the same, it will store only the date difference.

IMHO you should not use the proprietary madzip container, but a standard one, like the .zip. There are several around, include our version used in SynProject or our ORM. It's faster than MadZip and decompression is in optimized asm. See [SynZip](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynZip.pas) unit for low-level compression and a simple .zip reader and writer, and more evolved classes in [SynZipFiles](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynZipFiles.pas) (used in SynProject). For a pure Delphi version, like madzip one, check the [PasZip](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=PasZip.pas) unit which is faster than madzip (but PasZip won't compile with Unicode Delphi, whereas SynZip does).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, best practice to assure file identity is *to store* content hashes (eg: CRC-32 or any other hash function) *and* the **file sizes**. Doing so will increase reliability by magnitude. RE: to store - there is no need to compute hash on contents known to be unchanged more than once.